# How to copy just a part of an attribute to the new XML using XSLT 1.0

Tags: xml, xslt

I need to copy just a part of an attribute to create a new XML, I have this as input :

```
<START> 
    <LIST>
        <PRODUCT name="ELEMENT1.HKL" code="12" >
            <SPEC>
                <available>yes</available>
            </SPEC>
        </PRODUCT>
        
        <PRODUCT name="ELEMENT2.HKL" code="14" >
            <SPEC>
                <available>yes</available>
            </SPEC>
        </PRODUCT>
        
    </LIST>
</START>
```

In the match element I need to copy the attribute name but just what is written before the dot,so I would have something like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><START>
   <LIST>
       <PRODUCT delivery="done" name="ELEMENT1">
           <SPEC>
               <available>yes</available>
           </SPEC>
       </PRODUCT>
       <PRODUCT code="14" name="ELEMENT2.HKL">
           <SPEC>
               <available>yes</available>
           </SPEC>
       </PRODUCT>
   </LIST>
</START>
```

And this is the XSLT that Im trying to use :

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:str="http://exslt.org/strings" 
extension-element-prefixes="str">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

   <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
     <xsl:copy>
       <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
     </xsl:copy>
   </xsl:template>
   
   <xsl:template match="PRODUCT/@code[.='12']">
       <xsl:attribute name="delivery">done</xsl:attribute> 
       <xsl:attribute name="name">
           <xsl:value-of select="substring-before(., '.')"/>   
       </xsl:attribute> 
   </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

But its not working, any idea on how I can make it works?.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `substring-before(., '.')`.

Comment: the problem is that I have more than one product and I match with another attribute, I will modify my question to make it more complete

Comment: I don't see how we could have guessed that, but just use e.g. `<xsl:template match="PRODUCT[@code = 12]/@name"><xsl:attribute name="{name()}"><xsl:value-of select="substring-before(., '.')"/></xsl:attribute></xsl:template>` obviously, to handle the `name` attribute. If you want to add another attribute, do that in e.g. `<xsl:template match="PRODUCT[@code = 12]"><PRODUCT delivery="done"><xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/></PRODUCT></xsl:template>`